# Find missing sequential files

Tags: sql, batch-file

I am trying to get missing filenames from my PC that contains TV episode summary files.

There are over 200 (TV shows) directories and each show has subfolders for each season and each season subfolder contains a spererate file for each episode.
Ex.:

> ```
> G:\TV_Shows\The BlackList\02\The.Blacklist.Season02Episode05.properties
> ```

Is it possible using SQL and batch file to look in each directory and find the max episode number and output any episode under that number that is not found?
I know that this is not foolproof and that if the max. episode is missing it will not be correct but I think it will be an acceptable risk.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: how does this have to do with sql?  you need a database to use sql.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not solve this problem as stated. I could, however, solve it using a pure Batch file, with _no_ SQL  **`;-)`**

Comment: I have SQL installed and can use xp_cmdshell if using SQL to do the logic would be easier. what would be the approach using pure batch?

Comment: This could be solved using pure batch scripting, but that relies on a clear and unambiguous naming convention. Anyway, you need to try something on your own and share your efforts, otherwise this question is too broad here...

Answer (score 0):

No, SQL isn't going to help you find missing files, unless you have some information in a SQL database.

If you have a list of filenames in a flat file, you could load those into a SQL database table.

And then write a SQL query against that table. But string manipulation is *not* a forte of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script (see the comments for help):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

::/* Facts/Restrictions:
::files must be named like `<show-name>.Season<season-num>Episode<episode-num>.properties`;
::the `<show-name>` portion must not contain `.Season` on its own,
::the `Episode` portion must follow the `.Season<season-num>` part;
::`<season-num>` and `<episode-num>` must begin at 1 and must not hold more than nine figures;
::`<season-num>` portion is checked against name of parent directory for numeric equality;
::`<show-name>` portion is not checked against name of parent directory of parent directory;
::`INFO:` outputs are returned at STDOUT and show number of shows/seasons/episodes;
::`ERROR:` outputs are returned at STDERR and indicate missing seasons/episodes;
::the desired numbers of seasons/episodes are unknown, so the last ones missing are undetected; */

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOTDIR=G:\TV_Shows"  & rem // (root directory containing all TV shows)
set "_PATTERN=*.properties" & rem // (file pattern to search in season directories)
set "_SEASONS=.Season"      & rem // (file name portion preceding season number)
set "_EPISODE=Episode"      & rem // (file name portion preceding episode number)

rem // Clear arrays:
for /F "delims==" %%F in ('2^> nul set SIZE[') do set "%%F="
for /F "delims==" %%F in ('2^> nul set NAME[') do set "%%F="

rem // Accumulate TV show information:
set /A "SIZE=0"
for /D %%C in ("%_ROOTDIR%\*") do (
    set /A "SIZE+=1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%I in ("!SIZE!") do (
        endlocal
        set "SHOW=%%~nxC"
        for /D %%D in ("%%~C\*") do (
            set "SEASON1=%%~nxD"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%E in ("!SEASON1!") do set "SEASON1=%%E"
            set /A "SEASON1+=0"
            for %%J in ("!SEASON1!") do (
                endlocal
                set /A "SIZE[%%~I_%%~J]=0"
                for %%F in ("%%~D\%_PATTERN%") do (
                    set "FILE=%%~nxF"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    set "SEASON2=!FILE:*%_SEASONS%=1!"
                    set "SEASON2=!SEASON2:*%_SEASONS%=1!"
                    set "EPISODE=!SEASON2:*%_EPISODE%=1!"
                    set /A "SEASON2+=0, EPISODE+=0"
                    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%E in ("!SEASON2:~1!") do set "SEASON2=%%E"
                    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%E in ("!EPISODE:~1!") do set "EPISODE=%%E"
                    set /A "SEASON2+=0, EPISODE+=0"
                    for %%K in ("!EPISODE!") do (
                        if !SEASON2! NEQ %%~J (
                            >&2 echo ERROR: Show %%~I, "!SHOW!": season %%~J folder contains season !SEASON2! file^^!
                        ) else (
                            endlocal
                            set "NAME[%%~I_%%~J_%%~K]=%%~nxC"
                            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                            if !SIZE[%%~I_%%~J]! LSS %%~K (
                                endlocal
                                set /A "SIZE[%%~I_%%~J]=%%~K"
                                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    endlocal
                )
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                if !SIZE[%%~I]! LSS %%~J (
                    endlocal
                    set /A "SIZE[%%~I]=%%~J"
                ) else endlocal
            )
        )
        set "NAME[%%~I]=%%~nxC"
    )
)

rem // Validate TV show information:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(INFO:  %SIZE% shows in total.
for /L %%I in (1,1,%SIZE%) do (
    if defined SIZE[%%I] (
        echo(INFO:  Show %%I, "!NAME[%%I]!": !SIZE[%%I]! seasons.
        for /L %%J in (1,1,!SIZE[%%I]!) do (
            if defined SIZE[%%I_%%J] (
                if !SIZE[%%I_%%J]! GTR 0 (
                    echo(INFO:  Show %%I, "!NAME[%%I]!"; season %%J: !SIZE[%%I_%%J]! episodes.
                    for /L %%K in (1,1,!SIZE[%%I_%%J]!) do (
                        if not defined NAME[%%I_%%J_%%K] (
                            >&2 echo(ERROR: Show %%I, "!NAME[%%I]!"; season %%J: episode %%K missing^^!
                        )
                    )
                ) else (
                    >&2 echo(ERROR: Show %%I, "!NAME[%%I]!"; season %%J: no episodes defined^^!
                )
            ) else (
                >&2 echo(ERROR: Show %%I, "!NAME[%%I]!": season %%J missing^^!
            )
        )
    ) else (
        >&2 echo(ERROR: Show %%I, "!NAME[%%I]!": no seasons defined^^!
    )
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```